# Julia - Frequency Tables to DataFrame

Tags: dataframe, julia

I just found this package [FreqTables](https://github.com/nalimilan/FreqTables.jl), which allows one to easily construct frequency tables from DataFrames (I'm using DataFrames.jl).

The following lines of code return me a frequency table:

```
df = CSV.read("exampledata.csv")
freqtable(df,:col_name)
```

My question is how to turn the output into a dataframe again. The output from the frequency table function seems to be a NamedArray, which I haven't been able turn into a dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this solution to work for me:

```
using DataFrames, FreqTables
ft = freqtable(df, :A)
df = DataFrame(A = [2,2,2,2,5,5,5], B = [1,1,1,6,6,6,6])
DataFrame(A = names(ft)[1], Freq = ft)
```

Result:

```
2×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ A     │ Freq  │
│     │ Int64 │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 2     │ 4     │
│ 2   │ 5     │ 3     │
```

Comment: `DataFrame(A=names(ft)[1], Freq=ft)` is enough.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 4):

This does not directly answer your question, but freq tables you can alternatively just write:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(A = [2,2,2,2,5,5,5])
7×1 DataFrame
│ Row │ A     │
│     │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 2     │
│ 2   │ 2     │
│ 3   │ 2     │
│ 4   │ 2     │
│ 5   │ 5     │
│ 6   │ 5     │
│ 7   │ 5     │

julia> combine(groupby(df, :A), nrow => :Freq)
2×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ A     │ Freq  │
│     │ Int64 │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 2     │ 4     │
│ 2   │ 5     │ 3     │
```

to get the same

Comment: Didn't know about this :Freq, this is good to know!

Answer (score 0):

The way to convert Named matrix to DataFrame is different for one or more columns.

For one column frequency,

```
using DataFrames, FreqTables
df = DataFrame(A = [2,2,2,2,5,5,5], B = [1,1,1,6,6,6,6])
ft = freqtable(df, :A)
DataFrame(A = names(ft)[1], Freq=ft)
```

If freqtable is obtained from more than 2 columns,

```
ft = freqtable(df, :A, :B)
df_ft = DataFrame(ft |> Array, names(ft)[2] .|> string)
df_ft[:, :row] = names(ft)[1]
```

It is noted that changing index is not allowed in julia. See this post.
[Is it possible to set a chosen column as index in a julia dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64689023/is-it-possible-to-set-a-chosen-column-as-index-in-a-julia-dataframe)