# Is it possible to set a chosen column as index in a julia dataframe?

Tags: dataframe, julia

`dataframes` in pandas are indexed in one or more numerical and/or string columns. Particularly, after a `groupby` operation, the output is a dataframe where the new index is given by the groups.

Similarly, julia dataframes always have a column named `Row` which I think is equivalent to the index in pandas. However, after groupby operations, julia dataframes don't use the groups as the new index. Here is a working example:

```
using RDatasets;
using DataFrames;
using StatsBase;

df = dataset("Ecdat","Cigarette");

gdf = groupby(df, "Year");

combine(gdf, "Income" => mean)
```

Output:

```
11×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ Year  │ Income_mean │
│     │ Int32 │ Float64     │
├─────┼───────┼─────────────┤
│ 1   │ 1985  │ 7.20845e7   │
│ 2   │ 1986  │ 7.61923e7   │
│ 3   │ 1987  │ 8.13253e7   │
│ 4   │ 1988  │ 8.77016e7   │
│ 5   │ 1989  │ 9.44374e7   │
│ 6   │ 1990  │ 1.00666e8   │
│ 7   │ 1991  │ 1.04361e8   │
│ 8   │ 1992  │ 1.10775e8   │
│ 9   │ 1993  │ 1.1534e8    │
│ 10  │ 1994  │ 1.21145e8   │
│ 11  │ 1995  │ 1.27673e8   │
```

Even if the creation of the new index isn't done automatically, I wonder if there is a way to manually set a chosen column as index. I discover the method `setindex!` reading the [documentation](https://juliadata.github.io/DataFrames.jl/stable/lib/indexing/#General-rules). However, I wasn't able to use this method. I tried:

```
#create new df
income = combine(gdf, "Income" => mean)
#set index
setindex!(income, "Year")
```

which gives the error:

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching setindex!(::DataFrame, ::String)
```

I think that I have misused the command. What am I doing wrong here? Is it possible to manually set an index in a julia dataframe using one or more chosen columns?

Comment: The "Row" column you see when you display the `DataFrame` is just there for show--there is no default column named "Row" in a `DataFrame`. Is there a reason you _need_ an index column in the first place?

Comment: I need an index to create pivot tables to later convert to latex. I like this feature in pandas groupby and pivot_table. I also like multi-index and so on. I just want it in julia too.

Comment: @Lucas To be clear, you ***can*** pivot a `DataFrame` with DataFrames.jl. See [the docs](https://juliadata.github.io/DataFrames.jl/stable/man/reshaping_and_pivoting/). If you have further questions about table operations on `DataFrame`s, please open additional Stack Overflow questions with the specific problem you are facing. :)

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75635806/how-to-set-a-index-in-julias-dataframe

Comment: The answer is that DataFrames uses groupby to set table indexes.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/75636655/1048959

Answer (score 7, accepted):

DataFrames.jl does not currently allow specifying an index for a data frame. The `Row` column is just there for printing---it's not actually part of the data frame.

However, DataFrames.jl provides all the usual table operations, such as joins, transformations, filters, aggregations, and pivots. Support for these operations does not require having a table index. A [table index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index) is a structure used by databases (and by Pandas) to speed up certain table operations, at the cost of additional memory usage and the cost of creating the index.

The `setindex!` function you discovered is actually a method from Base Julia that is used to customize the indexing behavior for custom types. For example, `x[1] = 42` is equivalent to `setindex!(x, 42, 1)`.  Overloading this method allows you to customize the indexing behavior for types that you create.

The docstrings for `Base.setindex!` can be found [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.setindex!) and [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.setindex!-Tuple%7BAbstractArray,Any,Vararg%7BAny,N%7D%20where%20N%7D).

If you really need a table with an index, you could try [IndexedTables.jl](https://github.com/JuliaData/IndexedTables.jl).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Hopefully, `DataFrames` library will add this feature in the future.

Comment: Can you please comment for what operations you need the index for that are not currently supported? In DataFrames.jl the normal way to work if you need an index is to use `groupby`.

Comment: I like the whole set of index methods in pd (`set_index`, `reset_index`, and `reindex`). They are convenient and simple. For example, if I want a table in latex with a statistic from groups I just type `df.groupby("species").agg({k:mean for k in ["petal_length", "petal_width"]}. to_latex()` or if I want to compute the % in columns I will just iterate over columns in `100*df.col=df.col/df.col.sum()` after run `df.set_index("species")`. In both cases, `DataFrames.jl` will treat species as a regular column which create an undesired output in first operation and simply don't work in the second

Comment: @LucasCavalcantiRodrigues The use of `Not(cols)` as a selector might be helpful for grabbing excluding the groupby keys from a selection. e.g., `df2 = combine(groupby(df1, gb_cols), f); df[!, Not(gb_cols)]`