# How to set a index in Julia's DataFrame?

Tags: dataframe, julia

I have a DataFrame dfPaths as follows (I am using Julia)

[image]

I would like to define the column arc as the index of this dataFrame, so later I can use dfPaths[arc, "to"] to access the column "to" of a specific arc.

I know that in this example, arc = row, but in the future, I may have different values for the arc and not a sequential number.

I have tried to use setindex! but without success.
I would like to have the same result as df.set_index() from Python.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Look at `sort!(dfPaths :arc)`

Comment: I agree with what @DanGetz said - the reason `setindex!` didn't work is because it's used to modify values (not only for data frames, but for pretty much every collection whose value can be modified). For example `v[2] = 1` is actually a call to `setindex!(v, 1, 2)`, and `v[2]` is `getindex(v, 2)`. Sorting will only work if you know that the values in `arc` are consecutive and unique, but otherwise it's a sound solution!

Comment: It doesn't have something like .set_index() as we have in python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DataFrames.jl uses a different method of setting an index.

Do the following:

```
julia> dfPaths = DataFrame(arc=["a", "b", "a", "c", "d"], from=[1,1,2,3,2], to=[2,3,3,2,4])
5×3 DataFrame
 Row │ arc     from   to
     │ String  Int64  Int64
─────┼──────────────────────
   1 │ a           1      2
   2 │ b           1      3
   3 │ a           2      3
   4 │ c           3      2
   5 │ d           2      4

julia> gdf = groupby(dfPaths, :arc);

julia> gdf[("a",)]
2×3 SubDataFrame
 Row │ arc     from   to
     │ String  Int64  Int64
─────┼──────────────────────
   1 │ a           1      2
   2 │ a           2      3

julia> gdf[("b",)]
1×3 SubDataFrame
 Row │ arc     from   to
     │ String  Int64  Int64
─────┼──────────────────────
   1 │ b           1      3
```

Note that:

1. you always get a data frame when indexing (DataFrames.jl is strict about handling dimensions when indexing, you will always get a data frame); this means that if you expect the index to be unique write e.g. `only(gdf[("b",)])["from"]` then if it is indeed unique you get a value of the column and if it is not unique then you get an error.
2. you are always required to pass a tuple (other types are also allowed, but this is a side point). In pandas you in general also use tuples, but you can skip this. Again currently - in DataFrames.jl we opt to be strict here - you need to type a bit more, but you are sure that what gets executed is exactly what you meant.
3. Indexing in DataFrames.jl is always fast (i.e. O(1)), while in pandas it is not guaranteed (and lookup speed in some cases can be as slow as O(n)).